# How use add method Extjs component to another Extjs component (moderntoolkit)

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch, extjs6

How to add component to other, like a Ext.Viewport.add method?
For exaple I have defined panel, and want to add some component (panel) using function. I use 6.2.0, modern toolkit.
This example hasn't done positive result:

```
    Ext.onReady(function(){
var bigPannel=Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            title: 'Ext JS 4',
            width: 300,
            height: 200,
            id : 'bigPannel',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    Ext.getCmp('bigPannel').add({
            title: 'panel2',
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            html:'Hello!'
    });
})
```

Please help me understand, how to add component to other component.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? I ask because as your code is shown, when put into fiddle.sencha.com and using the Modern toolkit, nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you need to grab bigPannel with ext.getCmp.. instead get the var directly and add to it like this:

```
    Ext.onReady(function () {
        var bigPannel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            title: 'Ext JS 4',
            width: 300,
            height: 200,
            id: 'bigPannel',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });

        bigPannel.add({
            title: 'panel2',
            width: 100,
            height: 100
        })
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for example but it havn't worked. I have to use ext.getCmp, cause I wish add 'panel2' to panel, which was defined above. IdOfDefinedObject.add('panel2') didn't work: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Comment: @Tyomik_mnemonic, that does work as bigPannel is already an Ext JS object and bigPannel.add() would work as expected. It is also preferable to use this method and not using Ext.getCmp(). Ext.getCmp() uses the id, in your code above you could have a conflict with the var and the id...